# How to get top x rows within each group in a large file using bash

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I am using bash 3.2.53. I cannot use sql. sed,awk are preferable.

I have a huge data file with 100million rows. Each row has 3 columns => word1, word2 and count. These are in sorted order of word1 (ascending) and count (descending). I need top 3 rows for each unique word1 along with the count. If a word has < 3 rows then I need al the rows for that word.

**Sample file:**

```
acceleration in 26
acceleration of 18
accent and 104
accent i 62
accent is 61
accent the 51
accent in 37
accented with 90
accented by 25
accented the 11
accented and 2
accented english 2
```

**My desired output:**

```
acceleration in 26
acceleration of 18
accent and 104
accent i 62
accent is 61
accented with 90
accented by 25
accented the 11
```

Comment: Etan - thanks for fixing the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input is sorted the following should work.

```
awk 'word!=$1{count=1;word=$1} count<=3{print; count++}'
```

#### Explanation

When the first word on the current line doesn't match the last seen word reset our count and store the new word:

```
word!=$1{count=1;word=$1}
```

When our count is less than or equal to three print the line and increment count:

```
count<=3{print; count++}
```

Comment: Etan, I am doing something similar but cannot get it to work. I am weak in awk. I have a similar scenario but now I have 3 words and a count. The first 2 words are sorted in ascending and the count is descending. I need the top 3 rows based on the first 2 words. I have created a new column with word1+word2 and then using your script and it works. But trying to see if there is any cool awk script to do the same.  Thanks

Comment: awk 'word!=$1 $2{count=1;word=$1 $2} count<=3{print; count++}'

Comment: @Viswa That's the right idea though you might want to stick a separator in there (something like `SUBSEP` which isn't likely to be in any of your words) to protect against two small words being equivalent to one longer word (unlikely, especially in this case, but generally worth being safe).

Comment: Thanks Etan for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

awk 'word!=$1 $2{count=1;word=$1 $2} count<=3{print; count++}'

The solution provided by Eaton is correct for the original question. However, if we need to get top x rows within each group based on 2 columns then the above will work since it takes 2 words into account.

Comment: awesome, you answered your own question. Please be so kind and add some additional explanation how this solution is different to the other answer and what it does – so other readers can profit from your answer as well. In 2 days then you should be able to accept your own answer, if you think it is more helpful than the other answers.